# How to calculate stock in 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the first table like this (tbl_med)

```
id_med  name    stock
1       abc      10
2       bcd      15
3       efd      11
```

And the second table like this (tbl_trans)

```
id_trans   id_med  qty
1          1       4      
2          1       2      
3          2       3
```

How to calculate last stock or left stock in the firs table?
I tried this but it's not show left stock for id_med 3

```
SELECT tbl_med.stock, tbl_med.id_med, tbl_med.stock - SUM(tbl_trans.qty) AS stock_left FROM tbl_med
JOIN tbl_trans ON  tbl_med.id_med= tbl_trans.id_med
GROUP BY tbl_med.id_med
```

Comment: Edit your question and explain the calculation you want and the desired results.

Comment: Usually you will not calculate remaining stock due to performance reasons. Update your stock table when you record a transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need `coalesce()` and `left join`:

```
SELECT m.stock, m.id_med, m.stock - COALESCE(SUM(t.qty), 0) AS stock_left
FROM tbl_med m LEFT JOIN
     tbl_trans t
     ON m.id_med = t.id_med
GROUP BY m.id_med;
```

Note that usually having unaggregated columns in the `SELECT` that are not `GROUP BY` keys is an error in SQL.  However, it works fine if the `GROUP BY` has the primary key of the table.  I assume `id_med` is the primary key of `tbl_med`.

Comment: Woah thank you very much! I don't know about COALESCE function yet and i wrong to just write "JOIN" not "LEFT JOIN" because i want to select all from tbl_med